# For loop for an avocado data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, indexing

I keep getting the following error in my for loop:

`KeyError: "['California Total Sales'] not in index"`

I am unsure why the above is not in my index?

```
df101 = pd.DataFrame

for region in df['region'].unique()[:5]:
    print(region)

    regionalsales_df = df.copy()[df['region']==region]
    #regionalsales_df.set_index('Date')
    regionalsales_df.sort_index(inplace=True)

    regionalsales_df[f"{region}Total Sales"] = regionalsales_df['AveragePrice']*regionalsales_df['Total Volume']

    if df101.empty:
        df101 = regionalsales_df[[f"{region} Total Sales"]]

    else:
        df101 = df101.join(regionalsales_df[f"{region} Total Sales"])

df101
```

I am trying to get a dataframe in which the index is the date and the columns are the region total sales

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To be able to help you and answer your question it would be easier for people to see how your data looks like. So can you add some example data, 5 - 10 rows is sufficient to understand your problem.

Comment: Do you have a space typo in your script as well? You create `regionalsales_df[f"{region}Total Sales"]` and you call `regionalsales_df[[f"{region} Total Sales"]]`

Comment: That is it, that seems to have fixed it. I have been staring at it for so long I must have missed it. Thank you very much I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just df.groupby("region").sum()

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little bit more, in order to let more user benefit from it.